# Webscraping with rvest in R

Tags: r

I would like to scrape this page, however, it returns an empty data frame, is there a way how to web scrape this page?

```
# Test
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno"
page <- read_html(link)

name <- page %>% html_elements("name ng-binding") %>% html_text()
price <- page %>% html_elements('norm-price ng-binding') %>% html_text()

flat = data.frame(name, price, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Most modern webpages use a lot of javascript to add content to their pages after the initial page loads. Tools like rvest cannot run the javascript necessary to modify the pages. When seeing what's "really" on the page be sure to check the page "Source", not the "Elements" in your developer tools. If you need to get values added by javascript then you'll need to use something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should get you your desired output:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno?_escaped_fragment_="
page <- read_html(link)

name <- page %>% 
  html_elements(".name.ng-binding") %>% 
  html_text()

price <- page %>% 
  html_elements(".norm-price.ng-binding") %>% 
  html_text()
```

This returns

```r
name

#>  [1] "Prodej bytu 2+1 59 m²"   "Prodej bytu 3+kk 72 m²"  "Prodej bytu 3+kk 103 m²"
#>  [4] "Prodej bytu 2+kk 46 m²"  "Prodej bytu 3+1 72 m²"   "Prodej bytu 2+kk 84 m²" 
#>  [7] "Prodej bytu 1+kk 57 m²"  "Prodej bytu 2+kk 40 m²"  "Prodej bytu 2+kk 38 m²" 
#> [10] "Prodej bytu 2+kk 85 m²"  "Prodej bytu 2+kk 50 m²"  "Prodej bytu 3+1 77 m²"  
#> [13] "Prodej bytu 3+1 150 m²"  "Prodej bytu 3+1 75 m²"   "Prodej bytu 2+1 80 m²"  
#> [16] "Prodej bytu 1+1 34 m²"   "Prodej bytu 3+1 130 m²"  "Prodej bytu 3+kk 70 m²" 
#> [19] "Prodej bytu 2+kk 48 m²"  "Prodej bytu 2+kk 48 m²"  "Prodej bytu 2+1 61 m²"
```

and

```r
price

#>  [1] "6 000 000 Kč"  "7 490 000 Kč"  "11 680 000 Kč" "4 490 000 Kč"  "6 490 000 Kč" 
#>  [6] "6 490 000 Kč"  "5 249 000 Kč"  "3 990 000 Kč"  "3 790 000 Kč"  "6 990 000 Kč" 
#> [11] "4 790 000 Kč"  "5 990 000 Kč"  "9 500 000 Kč"  "6 890 000 Kč"  "7 999 000 Kč" 
#> [16] "4 850 000 Kč"  "10 880 000 Kč" "6 600 000 Kč"  "5 850 000 Kč"  "5 850 000 Kč" 
#> [21] "6 500 000 Kč"
```

#### Edit: scraping multiple pages

We scrape multiple pages and store the results in a list:

```r
my_list <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  link <- paste0("https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno?strana=", i, "_escaped_fragment_=")
  
  page <- read_html(link)
  
  name <- page %>% 
    html_elements(".name.ng-binding") %>% 
    html_text()
  
  price <- page %>% 
    html_elements(".norm-price.ng-binding") %>% 
    html_text()
  
  my_list[[i]] <- list(link, name, price)
}
```

You could access the pages (for example the first page) by

```r
my_list[[1]]
```

or the prices on the first page by

```r
my_list[[c(1, 3)]]
# or
my_list[[1]][[3]]
```

Comment: Thank you it works nice with one page, but I would like to use it in a for loop: 
for (page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 25, by = 1)) {
  link = paste0("https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno?strana=", page_result, "?_escaped_fragment_=")
  
  page <- read_html(link)
  
  price <- page %>% 
    html_elements(".norm-price.ng-binding") %>% 
    html_text()
  
  name <- page %>% 
    html_elements(".name.ng-binding") %>% 
    html_text()
  
  flat <- data.frame(price, name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
}

Comment: Where to set the number of pages? Thank you

Comment: You missed this part in your original question...

Comment: Yes, please is it possible to use this for a loop? I mean you got your answer only I would need to come up with a solution for a loop.

Comment: @JaroslavKotrba Updated the answer.